# How do I download/read html from a website line by line from Android Java App?

Tags: java, android, html, traffic

I'm currently working on an App that gets a specific text from different sites to process them.
Right now I'm using:

```
URL             textUrl         = new URL(url);
InputStream     in              = textUrl.openStream();
BufferedReader  bufferReader    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder   stringText      = new StringBuilder();
String          bufferString;

while ((bufferString = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (bufferString.indexOf("FIND ME AFTER TEXT") > -1) {
        break;
    }
    stringText.append(bufferString);
}

bufferReader.close();
output = stringText.toString();
```

This is, as you might see, downloading the whole html code of the specified page and reads it line by line.

But as the specific text that I'm looking for is at the beginning of those pages, my intention is not to only read it line by line, but also download only the line that is currently processed, to save a lot of "unnecessary" traffic.
Is there a way to do this?  If so, how?

(Download only specific lines from html pages would be even better, but I guess that IS not possible)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can download until that specific line and then quit. It does probably not influence the server as the server will have output all already. Only somewhere on the line a buffer will not be emptied the right way.

Comment: thx, but how do I download line by line? Like this it downloads the whole thing and only put it in strings line by line. (for example, ´stringText´ goes only till the specific line but both traffic and full page size are 40kb insted of about 3kb traffic until it would reach the specific line)

Comment: You are already downoading line by line with .readLine(). And you stop already the 'download' when you break out having found 'FIND ME AFTER TEXT'. You did not tell how you determined traffic. But 40 KB is so small that it is obvious that Android read it in at once and buffered before you read it line by line.

Comment: Thats interesting, my problem is, that (depending on the user) it do search for the text on usualy about 10 and maybe a lot more pages. Lets stay at 10, so my app generates 400kb traffic insted of 30kb with one update. And as I intend to implement a method to update regulary, thats a lot of useless traffic. Is there a way to stop Android from doing so?

Comment: No. Don't think so. You have to change the servers to deliver the right info. Can you use search requests?

Comment: I sadly do not have any kind of access to the servers. And the text I'm looking for is inside a from php generated javascript var.

Comment: If you really are concerned about traffic size for the users of your app you could make your own server on the web. That new server queries the other servers for info. Your app will contact your server with such a request that only wanted info is send.